# Best way to detect logical connectors

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to detect logical connectors in a string (AND, OR, NOT) using Java. What I would like to do is:

- Given a string (e.g ((blue) AND (yellow) OR (pink)), separate each word and put them in a List. The result should be something like {"blue","yellow","pink"}

I know that for match the words, I need to use a regex like  \b(AND|OR|NOT)\b. 
But I don't know how return each word after or before the connector.

Other question: Is usefull use regex or maybe I have to use contains()?

Comment: you separate the words and then.. what you should with with the logical operators?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
String s = "((blue) AND (yellow) OR (pink))";
s = s.replaceAll("\\(|\\)", "");
String[] words = s.split("AND|OR|NOT");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(words));
```

Output:

```
[blue ,  yellow ,  pink]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string s="((blue) AND (yellow) OR (pink))";
s.split("\bAND\b|\bNOT\b|\bOR\b");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `string.split("AND|OR|NOT");`.

EDIT: oops, forgot \b:

`string.split("\b(AND|OR|NOT)\b");`

Answer (score 0):

Parsing this kind of strings is no task for regular expressions, regular expressions represent a finite predefined automaton.

you need to use some sort of pushdown automaton for this task.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushdown_automaton

The easiest way to do this, is with a recursion that identifies a "logical string structure"

`(...) AND (...)` or `(...) OR (...)`, `NOT (...)`, etc...

and strips the parenthesis, and repeats until you discover a string that doesn't match this kind of structure.

This string is what you're looking for.